# What I do for Glyphicons appear in Joomla! 3.3

Tags: joomla-3.x, fix-my-code, bootstrap, template-manager

I'm a Joomla beginner, and I'm creating a personal website using ***Bootstrap 3*** and ***Joomla! 3.3.*** I saw something about **Glyphicons** not work with the custom B3. [I used the Customizer]

My template has the following structure:

```
template/
 - css/ bootstrap.css | template.css | screen.css
 - fonts/ glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot | glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
          glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf | glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff  
 - images/ logo.png
 - js/ boostrap.js  
 - component.php
 - favicon.ico
 - index.html
 - index.php
 - template_thumbnail.png
 - template_preview.png
 - templateDetails.xml
```

In **bootstrap.css** file, `@font-face` looks like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

The default Bootstrap version loaded is **2.3.2** in ***Joomla!3.3***, but I'm using the Bootstrap version 3 loaded this way:

```
?php defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/bootstrap.css');
$doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/bootstrap.js', 'text/javascript');
?>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Are you importing the bootstrap css file correctly? How are you importing the Bootstrap css file? How are you trying to embed a glyphicon? Please show some code

Comment: When you call an icon, does your page throw up an error (check the console). Sometimes it can be as simple as a path issue and you'll see a message about a file not being found.

Comment: @Lodder, I trying use the bootstrap 3. I know that Joomla!3.3 don't work with <link rel=...> within the <head> tag. In this case, how is the correct way to load this files[css & js]? As above?

Comment: @BrianPeat, the most basic icons to be loaded, such as print and mail in component are not loaded.

Comment: Where is the code of implementing glyphicon ? please add that so we can figure out.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't make clear if you load bootstrap 2 and bootstrap 3 at the same time, and also it's not clear how you try to use glyphicons in your code. The right (and working) way is for example:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
```